# PhpMailer Sent email content is show only plain text not contain with HTML styles

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, phpmailer, summernote

I use PhpMailer library in codeigniter for send an email, email sending process are working fine, i use summernote for write my email content, summernote generate HTML format what i edit in summernote, but while i send an email, recieved mail have just plain text, i don't know why it's happen..

Here i attach PhpMailer function,

```
function send_email_common_method($email_id,$password,$to,$subject,$content,$attach_file,$ccmailarray,$bccmailarray,$email_id_name) {
  include_once(APPPATH."third_party/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->Port = 465;//587
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = $email_id;
  $mail->Password = $password;
  $mail->setFrom($email_id, $email_id_name);
  $mail->addAddress($to);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->msgHTML(strip_tags($content));
  $mail->addAttachment($attach_file);
  foreach($ccmailarray as $ccarray)
  {
    $mail->AddCC($ccarray);
  }
  foreach($bccmailarray as $bccarray)
  {
    $mail->AddBCC($bccarray);
  }
  //print_r($mail);exit;
  if (!$mail->send()) {
    $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    return 0;
  //echo '<p id="para">'.$error.'</p>';exit;
  }
  else {
    return 1;
  }

}
```

And below i attach summernote view code,

```
<!--Wysiwyg editor : Summernote placeholder-->
<textarea name="reply_content_email" class="reply_content_email" id
   ="reply-mailbox-mail-compose"></textarea>
<p class="text-danger" id="reply_content_email_err"></p>
<!-- <div ></div> -->
<div class="pad-ver">
   <!--Send button-->
   <button id="mail-send-btn" type="submit" name="btn_submit"  class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="mailbox-psi-mail-send icon-lg icon-fw"></i> Reply Mail
   </button>
</div>
```

Any one can find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing all your HTML tags with the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
$mail->msgHTML(strip_tags($content));
```

Just pass `$content` without the `strip_tags` function.

Comment: Thanks @kopz , i didn't notice that, now it's working fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHPMailer then you may use

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

That will work for html format.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer sir, i already included this function, as per above @kopz answer it's working fine now

Comment: great. It's with different syntax. Hopefully will help someone else in furture.